# Несколько событий для передачи значений с формы 2 на форму 1

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть две формы с кодом (c# winforms vs2010):

```
Form1

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        if (frm2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(frm2.getItem());
        }
        frm2.Close();
        frm2.Dispose();
    }
}

From2

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        button2.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    public string getItem()
    {
        return textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить код, если на форме2 есть еще одна кнопка "button3.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;"? Т.е. пользователь может на форме2 нажать либо кнопку button1 либо button3, которые работают как "DialogResult.OK".

Т.е. для кнопки button3:

```
if (frm2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(frm2.getItem3());
            }

public string getItem3()
        {
            return textBox2.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Поправила вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private TextBox itemBox = null;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        button3.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        button2.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }

    public string getItem()
    {
        return (itemBox == null)? null : itemBox.Text;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemBox = textBox1;
    }
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        itemBox = textBox2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: @olga Не забудьте подсоединить обработчики событий к кнопкам.

Comment: В коде "if (frm2.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)" для button3_Click не работает. Значение textBox2 не возвращается. Возвращается только значение textBox1.

Comment: @olga Плохо дело (. Вы кнопке `DialogResult` назначили?

Comment: DialogResult.OK для button1. А если нажать button3,то itemBox не равно textBox2?

Comment: @olga Вы свойству `button3.DialogResult` присвоили какое-нибудь значенние?

Comment: нет. Не знаю какое?

Comment: @olga `DialogResult.OK`

Comment: Работает! Не догадалась написать два DialogResult.OK (думала что можно один только). button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;   button3.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; Спасибо!

Comment: @olga На здоровье. Поздравляю! Слева от ответа - знак "галочка".